# MinGW C++ using vector exit value 127

Tags: c++, windows, vector, mingw

I have a problem using vector in C++. I'm working with MinGW on Windows + NetBeans.

Following code:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv){
  vector<int> vec;
  return 0;
}
```

It compiles without any errors, but when run it always fails with exit value -1.073.741.511 or exit value 127 (that means ERROR_PROC_NOT_FOUND).

Starting the exe directly shows up with an error message like:

```
entrypoint '__gx_personality_v0' not fount in 'libstdc++-6.dll'.
```

I have already tried `-lstdc++` and

```
#include <cstdlib>
```

So what's the problem and how do I solve it?

Netbeans output:

```
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Josch/CppApplication_1'
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW1-Windows/cppapplication_1.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Josch/CppApplication_1'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW1-Windows
rm -f build/Debug/MinGW1-Windows/main.o.d
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF build/Debug/MinGW1-Windows/main.o.d -o build/Debug/MinGW1-Windows/main.o main.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW1-Windows
g++     -o dist/Debug/MinGW1-Windows/cppapplication_1 build/Debug/MinGW1-Windows/main.o 
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Josch/CppApplication_1'
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Josch/CppApplication_1'

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 4s)
```

EDIT: Of course main should return int - fixed that and added using namespace std;

Comment: `<cstdlib>` has nothing to do with `libstdc++` confusingly.

Comment: Show your command line, please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay I found a solution.

The problem was an installation of `MiKTeX` that was added to the `PATH` variable. So Windows linked to a different version of `libstdc++-6.dll`.

Finally I found two solutions:

1. Compile with `-static-libstdc++` to avoid wrong DLL being linked.
2. Copy `libstdc++-6.dll` from `MinGW\bin` into the same folder as the compiled EXE. This will cause windows to link always the correct version of the DLL.

Although the problem is very specific, I hope that it helps others too. ;)

Comment: Thanks for this! How did you determine where the "wrong" libstdc++-6.dll was? I'm getting the same errors, but I'm not sure what's causing a wrong version of the library to be used (it's not MiKTeX)

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply. You could use Microsoft's Process Explorer ( https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer ) to see which DLLs get loaded by a process. Hope this still helps you out!