# c++ vector causes runtime crash

Tags: c++, vector, netbeans, runtime

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<int> i;
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously there are no syntax or logical errors, and the runtime error is reminiscent of a missing dll, but I have no idea what could be missing.

> RUN FAILED (exit value -1,073,741,511, total time: 925ms)

Using NetBeans 8.2

MinGW 6.3.0

c++11

Comment: What happens if you comment out the vector? What about a simple Hello World program?

Comment: It works fine if no vector variables are declared. #include<vector> doesn't cause a crash.

Comment: any core file generated?

Comment: Nothing was generated by NetBeans, but I created a dump file from the task manager [here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/x5b3h89718o43ml/v.DMP/file)

Comment: It works fine on g++ 8.3 on my Fedora 29 machine

Comment: I found in stl_vector.h that ~_Vector_base() at line 159 is showing the error "Method ~_Vector_base does not have declaration"

Comment: Found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17867516/mingw-c-using-vector-exit-value-127?rq=1